# jquery bind click event to class? datatables ajax deleting row from a tag

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables and in a table which has two columns the second columns has a text link with the class .deletecomp when clicked ajax deletes the entry from the database but i'm having trouble refreshing the table.

I added the code below the // Test delete tr comment and when I click any tr in the table it deletes the row and refreshes the table. AJAX is fired and the entry in the db table is removed. How can I change this function to work with my Delete text link which has the .deletecomp class

This is how I am initializing the table

```
    oTableVC = $('#viewcomp').dataTable( {
        "sDom":'t<"bottom"filp><"clear">',
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [ 
            null,
            null
            ]
    } 
    );
    //Test delete tr
    $("#viewcomp tbody tr").live('click', function () {
        oTableVC.fnDeleteRow( this );
    });

});
```

And this is the AJAX which deletes the db entry

```
$(".deletecomp").live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    cidstring = $(this).attr("id");
    cidArr = cidstring.split("-");
    cid = cidArr[1];
    var url = 'http://domain.com/ajaxdeletecomp?format=json';

    $.post(url, { id: cid},function(ajaxdata) {
        //deleting row from table

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this plugin before; however based on your code the following should do the trick:

```
// Needs to be declared in the the JS Document outside of any functions //
var oTableVC = $('#viewcomp').dataTable( {
    "sDom":'t<"bottom"filp><"clear">',
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [ 
        null,
        null
        ]
    } 
);


$(".deletecomp").live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    cidstring = $(this).attr("id");
    cidArr = cidstring.split("-");
    cid = cidArr[1];
    var url = 'http://domain.com/ajaxdeletecomp?format=json';
    var $target = $(this).closest('tr'); // Add Reference </tr> of Link

    $.post(url, { id: cid},function(ajaxdata) {
        //deleting row from table
        oTableVC.fnDeleteRow( $target ); // Deletes Row
    });
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: We tried placing the fnDeleteRow function there but it's not firing

Comment: @Anagio The oTableVC var is most likely out of scope; take a look at my edit. Make sure to add the var part as above.

Comment: I have still nothing... I had tested fnClearTable(); to see if it fires when placed above the var url and when the delete link was clicked the table cleared. I don't see why DeleteRow isn't working

Comment: Is the $.post() working correctly? For example if you place a console.log('Complete'); inside the callback does it log?